# dual view monitors for one desktop on ati

Tags: 11.10, unity, multiple-monitors, resolution

How do i get dual view (two monitors with Full-HD-resolution) for one desktop on unity with an ati card on ubuntu 11.10?
on 11.04 all worked fine. 
Now i have the problem, that after customizing on "AMD Catalyst Control Center (Administrative)" nothing happens. And if i open it again, the standard configuration is shown again.

On Ubuntu system settings i also get a problem. There is a message that the virtual resolution is too high (the maximum for both monitors seems to be 1920*1080).

I have two monitors with the following resolution: 1920*1080. So there must be a way to get the virtual resolution for 3840*1080. Again: This worked for me on 11.04. And i customized it with "AMD Catalyst Control Center".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

open a terminal and run:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

then run the following command to reconfigure the dual monitor setup:

```
sudo amdcccle
```

Comment: thx: it also works if i only start the CCC from terminal with "sudo amdcccle"