# Dual monitor resolution changing after reboot with AMD CCC

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors, fglrx

I have 2 monitors connected to my machine which is running Ubuntu 13.04 x64, one of which has a resolution of 1680x1050 and the other is 1280x1024.  I have a AMD A10 5800K processor which includes Radeon HD 7660D integrated graphics.  I have installed the fglrx and fglrx-updates drivers and both of them are giving me the same problem:

When I reboot my machine, the resolution of both monitors are set to 1280x1024.  I then go in to AMD CCC in administrative mode and set the main monitor back to 1680x1050 which works fine until I reboot the machine.

Is there anyway to make this configuration persistent across reboots?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method and it works.

Open a terminal and type:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

In your `xorg` file, go to this section:

```
    Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Virtual   1680 1680
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
    EndSection
```

add this code or modify:

```
virtual 1680 1680
```

try changing these values with a number higher than your resolution of monitor.
Restart the computer.

source: [How can I set up dual monitor display with ATI driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71457/how-can-i-set-up-dual-monitor-display-with-ati-driver/103310#103310)

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to resurrect a dead thread, but I wound up here and thought I would share what FINALLY worked for me.  This problem STILL exists with dual monitor setups even in 14.04.  Here is what I did to fix it in 14.04/openbox/lubuntu.

Get driver http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx

Install without making a distro specific package.

Reboot.

Run `aticonfig --initial`

Reboot.

Run `sudo amdcccle` and do your setup dance restarting x or rebooting.

My settings now persist across reboots with dual displays.