# AMD Catalyst Control Center not saving multi monitor settings

Tags: drivers, ati, multiple-monitors, fglrx

So I am using `gksu amdcccle` to make changes but for some reason whenever I select the 'Multi-display desktop with display(s)' option to extend my desktop the changes never save on restart or re-log. The odd thing is that other changes I make, like enabling tear free desktop seem to save and work fine. Another thing, when I log out the user/password box is only on 1 screen with just a wallpaper on the other implying the extended display options are working correctly, but as soon as I log back in they go back to mirrored.

I am on the proprietary fglrx drivers installed using the additional drivers method on Ubuntu 13.10 with a HD 5870.

I am pretty new to Linux, any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if I left out some important information.

Comment: Do you open CCC as sudo/root?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I found the answer in the site

the bug hasnt been fixed yet !!!

see below

ATI Catalyst doesn't retain changes after reboot when setting extended display

After using amdcccle to set the monitors as required, apply and exit, then from System -> Preferences -> Screen Resolution [or Monitors in Debian], verify it is showing the resolution you configured in amdcccle and click apply.

The next time you restart or login the settings will be preserved. shareimprove this answer

answered Jul 4 '12 at 20:03 Dog Ears 1585

Thanks, this is a really stupid bug still present in whatever version of fglrx is in Ubuntu 12.10. I've just been resetting the setting each time on boot which is a huge pain. – Ibrahim Feb 24 at 2:45

Very simple, this should be a bug and fixed in CCC. I'm guessing all this solution is doing is writing the settings created in CCC to xorg? Strange. Thanks for your guidance, very helpful. – TryTryAgain Mar 8 at 19:54

Comment: Do you have a link to a bug report, e.g. Launchpad? A Lucid one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/551475